# Who there is at hotel or Who is at hotel?

Tags: clauses

1.There is a party at hotel.

> (A)Question   - Where is there a party? (at hotel)
>       (B)noun clause- Where there is a party.

2.There is a man at the hotel.

> (A)Question   - Who is there at the hotel? (a man)
>       (B)Noun clause- Who there is at the hotel.

I know here 1A and 1B are correct.

but (1) I want to know whether 2A and 2B is correct?

(2) If 2A and 2B is correct, what is the difference between noun clauses 'Who **there** is at the hotel.' and 'who is at the hotel.'?

Comment: In American English, we don't say *at hotel.*

Answer (score 1):

As CarSmack noted, you need an article with *hotel*. That aside, to answer your questions:

(1) Both *who is there at the hotel?* and *who there is at the hotel* are both correct.

The main difference between them is that *who is there at the hotel?* is a **question**, and *who there is at the hotel* is not a question, it is a (noun) phrase, not even a complete sentence.

The same is true for *where is (there) a party?* and *where there is a party*.

The noun phrases are only a *part* of a complete sentence, they cannot be used on their own. You *certainly* should not use them on there own as a question - this is a common mistake!

Examples of how to use the noun phrases:

> Where there is a party, John will be found!
>   Please inform who there is at the hotel that they should leave immediately.

Note that the last sentence is more natural with *whoever*:

> Please inform whoever there is at the hotel that they should leave immediately.

(2) As for the difference between "who is at the hotel" and "who there is at the hotel":
With the *there*, because of the word order, it can only be a noun phrase, not a full question. Without *there* it can be a question.

Including *there* seems to just give extra emphasis to the location (at the hotel) although leaving it out sounds more natural if I look at my last sentence, and a version without:

> Please inform whoever there is at the hotel that they should leave immediately.
>   Please inform whoever is at the hotel that they should leave immediately.

*If* you use *there*, you *have* to use a verb expressing existence. You cannot use any other verbs after there:

> *Please inform whoever there sleeps at the hotel that they should leave immediately.*wrong!!*
>   Please inform whoever sleeps at the hotel that they should leave immediately.*correct!!*

Answer (score 0):

Singular nouns are usually preceded by an indefinite article ("a"/"an") or the definite article ("the"). So either:

- "Who is at *a* hotel", or
- "Who is at *the* hotel".